# Spring boot app gracefully catch the SIGTERM signal and invoke the predestroy method

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application which needs to clear or clean up the resources when we kill the process using kill pid. @predestroy annotated method is not working and not getting called. Please suggest how can we catch the SIGTERM and invoke the predestroy method

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this? I have the same issue where Hikari pool is shutting down before @PreDestroy method is executed

Answer (score 12):

Ideally, it should work but make sure `SIGTERM` is called and not `SIGKILL`

I have a few cases where we run spring boot application

**Docker**

When you execute `docker stop` what happens behind the scene is

> Stop one or more running containers The main process inside the
> container will receive SIGTERM, and after a grace period, SIGKILL

**kill**

`kill 9955`  =>  SIGTERM is called
`kill -9 9955` => SIGKILL is called

[Refer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59811/kill-pid-not-really-killing-the-process-why) for more detail on kill.

**Now coming back to `@PreDestroy`**

I have added following line in my SpringBoot Application

```
@PreDestroy
public void tearDown() {
    System.out.println("Shutting Down...............the ");
}
```

I get following output when I do `kill portno`

```
2019-01-04 10:52:44.776  INFO o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler / shutdown - 208 : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2019-01-04 10:52:44.783  INFO o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor / shutdown - 208 : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-01-04 10:52:44.785  INFO o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean / destroy - 597 : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-01-04 10:52:44.792  INFO c.z.h.HikariDataSource / close - 350 : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2019-01-04 10:52:44.800  INFO c.z.h.HikariDataSource / close - 352 : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
Shutting Down...............
```

As you can see in Log I have 2 Scheduler Task running and JPA Entity Manager.
On receiving `SIGTERM` it closes all that first and finally call preDestory.

I am not sure what more clean up you need to do but do make sure if its already cleaned.

**Shut down embedded servlet container gracefully**

You can also customize and write your own shutdown gracefully hook.
[Refer to this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4657#issuecomment-161354811) good discussion and sample code on this

**Restructure embedded web server packages**

*Pls be mindful of the sample code from above link*. If you are using newer version of Springboot chances are **package might be missing.**

Refer this for [more detail on changes methods and classes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/67556ba8eaf22a352b03fe197a0c452f695835a6)

Answer (score 5):

Just small addition to @MyTwoCents answer for `@PreDestroy` and **Docker** -> ensure to use `ENTRYPOINT` instead of `CMD` or `RUN` - only then you will run application as a **main process** and SIGTERM will be sent to your application

Comment: The `exec` form can even be used with the `CMD` [instruction](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd).